# bootstrap buttons have no horizontal padding when rendered via JSF

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jsf, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm noticing same odd behaviour which I can't explain...

Where I have a series of buttons:

```
    <h:commandButton value="foo" actionListener="#{foo.foo}" styleClass="btn btn-danger">
        <f:ajax render=":form"></f:ajax>
    </h:commandButton>
    <h:commandButton value="bar" actionListener="#{foo.bar}" styleClass="btn btn-danger">
        <f:ajax render=":form"></f:ajax>
    </h:commandButton>
    <h:commandButton value="car" actionListener="#{foo.car}" styleClass="btn btn-danger">
        <f:ajax render=":form"></f:ajax>
    </h:commandButton>
```

They are all rendered squashed together:

[image: squashed buttons]

With rendered markup (via Chrome Inspect Element):

```
<input id="j_idt92" type="submit" name="j_idt92" value="foo" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'action',0,'form');return false">
<input id="j_idt92" type="submit" name="j_idt92" value="bar" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'action',0,'form');return false">
<input id="j_idt92" type="submit" name="j_idt92" value="car" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'action',0,'form');return false">
```

Now if I take this markup (after adding closing slashes to the input tags) and drop it right in my view I see:

[image: notsquashed buttons]

If i define a set of vanilla buttons with `class="btn btn-danger"` then they appear spaced as expected.

What would cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because jsf components **trim** spaces.To achieve what you want put #{' '} expression between buttons

```
<h:commandButton value="foo" actionListener="#{foo.foo}" styleClass="btn btn-danger">#{' '}
    <f:ajax render=":form"></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>
<h:commandButton value="bar" actionListener="#{foo.bar}" styleClass="btn btn-danger">#{' '}
    <f:ajax render=":form"></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>
<h:commandButton value="car" actionListener="#{foo.car}" styleClass="btn btn-danger">
    <f:ajax render=":form"></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>
```

Comment: What whitespace is it trimming exactly?

Comment: spaces , newlines, tabs

Comment: Unfortunately as per http://ocpsoft.org/java/undocumented-jsf/ I think you are right.  JSF strikes again.  I'll mark your answer as correct unless someone else can come in with a better solution in the next day or so.